# Run Product Filter Javascript On Page Template

Tags: functions, javascript, page-template

I am trying to run the below script on a vehicles WordPress page template. The page template shows products that are the result of a product filter (make, model, year, transmission, etc..).
The product filter uses Javascript. This is replacing a current WordPress product filter that is too slow.

The page the products are displayed on is www.example.com/vehicles

I did try adding the script to the content editor, it displayed correctly on the page, but for some reason the URL keeps changing (need to figure out that strange issue).
Also, I am thinking this script should not be in the page content editor or in the page template, but instead located in the functions.php file.

I am not sure what the code should be in the functions.php file and also the code needed for the page template to call the script.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<link href="https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/runtime-main.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/chunk.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

Part Two:

How do I call this type of PHP function in the page template?

The PHP function will need to be called in the page template that shows the product filter results. We will call this the page.php page template.
Here is sample code of that page template, with content towards the bottom that mentions "call PHP function my_custom_enqueue_scripts here"

```
<?php
/**
 * Full results page with product filter support to be shared across 
templates.
 *
* @package theme name
*/

?>
<div class="row pagetop">
<div class="small-12 medium-12 columns">
        <header class="page-headermore">
            <h1 class="page-title">
                <?php esc_html_e( 'Vehicles', 'acme' ); ?>
            </h1>
            <div class="breadcrumbs" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data- 
vocabulary.org/#">
                <?php
                if ( function_exists( 'bcn_display' ) ) {
                    bcn_display();
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </header>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row collapse">

<p>Call the my_custom_enqueue_scripts PHP function within this div.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WordPress, you should use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to load JavaScript files, and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) to load CSS files, and the functions should be called using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) action hook. Additionally, the theme needs to call `wp_head()` (in `header.php`) and `wp_footer()`.

And to enqueue a script only on specific pages, you would use a [conditional tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/references/list-of-conditional-tags/) like [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) in your case.

So this should work and be placed in the theme `functions.php` file:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_custom_enqueue_scripts() {
    // If the Page slug is 'vehicles', then we load the files.
    if ( is_page( 'vehicles' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chunk-styles', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/chunk.css', [], null );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main-styles', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/main.css', [], null );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'runtime-main', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/runtime-main.js', [], null );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chunk-js', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/chunk.js', [], null );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/main.js', [], null );
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

So here's what would happen with the above code:

1. WordPress checks if the URL satisfies a standard Page request/URL that may look like `https://example.com/vehicles`.
2. If so, WordPress will enqueue (i.e. register and load) the CSS and JS files referenced in the above code. So for example, you'd see these in the document's `head` (`<head>here</head>`):

   ```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/chunk.css" />
   ... other 'link'/'script'/HTML tags here ...
   <script src="https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/chunk.js"></script>
   ```

So the function (`my_custom_enqueue_scripts()`) should not need to be manually called anywhere in the source/HTML, because the function is hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and the function would be automatically called when WordPress calls that hook (i.e. functions/callbacks registered to run in that hook) on the `/vehicles` page.

But if you must print the `link` and `script` tags in the `div` as shown in the updated question, then you'd use [`wp_register_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) with [`wp_register_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_regiter_script/) in the above function and not `wp_enqueue_style()` with `wp_enqueue_script()`. So:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_custom_enqueue_scripts() {
    // If the Page slug is 'vehicles', then register the files.
    if ( is_page( 'vehicles' ) ) {
        wp_register_style( 'chunk-styles', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/chunk.css', [], null );
        wp_register_style( 'main-styles', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/main.css', [ 'chunk-styles' ], null );

        wp_register_script( 'runtime-main', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/runtime-main.js', [], null );
        wp_register_script( 'chunk-js', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/chunk.js', [ 'runtime-main' ], null );
        wp_register_script( 'main-js', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/main.js', [ 'chunk-js' ], null );
    }
}
```

And then in your `div`, call [`wp_print_styles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_print_styles/) and [`wp_print_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_print_scripts/):

```php
<div class="row collapse">
    <?php
        wp_print_styles( 'main-styles' ); // also loads chunk-styles
        wp_print_scripts( 'main-js' );    // also loads chunk-js and runtime-main
    ?>
</div>
```

#### A Better Practice: Load CSS files in `head`.

Yes, you should, despite `<link>` is allowed in `body`.

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_custom_enqueue_scripts() {
    // If the Page slug is 'vehicles', then enqueue the CSS and register the JS.
    if ( is_page( 'vehicles' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chunk-styles', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/chunk.css', [], null );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main-styles', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/css/main.css', [ 'chunk-styles' ], null );

        wp_register_script( 'runtime-main', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/runtime-main.js', [], null );
        wp_register_script( 'chunk-js', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/chunk.js', [ 'runtime-main' ], null );
        wp_register_script( 'main-js', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/main.js', [ 'chunk-js' ], null );
    }
}
```

And then in your `div`, call `wp_print_scripts()` *only*:

```php
<div class="row collapse">
    <?php
//      wp_print_styles( 'main-styles' ); // the files already loaded in 'head'
        wp_print_scripts( 'main-js' );    // also loads chunk-js and runtime-main
    ?>
</div>
```

#### Or Use the original PHP function and load the JS files in the footer.

Yes, just set the 5<sup>th</sup> parameter for `wp_enqueue_script()` to `true` which loads the script file in the page footer (printed somewhere before `</body>` or wherever you put the call to `wp_footer()`). E.g.

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'chunk-js', 'https://example.thirdparty.com/static/js/chunk.js', [], null, true );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed PHP function.
I edited my original question and added a "Part Two" and added the page template code. 
How do I call that type of PHP function on the page template?

Comment: Perhaps the updated answer can help? :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer and explanation. This is working great!