# combine Code 1 with Code 2

Tags: php, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, jquery, thumbnails

Code 1 - uses wp_list_categories to list product categories in columns of x categories up to a total of y, with a link to view all categories if there are more than y.

Code 2 - Later realising i needed thumbnails aswell, I tried using get_terms to retrieve the list and thumbnails. However it is just 1 long list and I am having a lot of trouble trying to apply the principles from the Code 1 to Code 2 to make it work.

This is Code 2:

```
<?php           
                $args = array(
                'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
                'title_li'   => '',
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'echo'       => 0,
                'show_count' => 0,
                'style'      => '',
                'parent'    => 0
                );

$get_cats = get_terms( $args );
        ?>
<div class="design">
   <div class="menu">
       <ul class="hoverimage">
<?php
    foreach ( $get_cats as $cat ) {
    $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 

   if($image == "") {
   $image = get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder-100x100.png';
    }
?>
    <li class="menu-item" data-image="<?php echo $image; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $cat ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
       </ul>
   </div>
    <div class="zoom-preview">
        <div class='img_container'>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    var imageContainer = '.img_container',
        imageList      = '.hoverimage',
        maxWidth       = 'parent', // parent or specific css width/  
        defImage       = '<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder-100x100.png';

    var $imageContainer = $(imageContainer).eq(0);
    var $imageList      = $(imageList).eq(0);
    if (maxWidth === 'parent') { maxWidth = $imageContainer.width() + 'px'; }
    //Load images and set hover::
    $imageList.find('li').each(function(index){
        if (typeof $(this).data('image') === 'string') {
            $imageContainer.append(
                "<img id='imageToggle"+index+
                "' src='"+$(this).data('image')+
                "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"; display:none;' />"
            );
            $(this).data("image","imageToggle"+index);
            $(this).hover(
                function(){ loadImage($(this).data('image')); },
                function(){ loadImage('imageToggleDef'); }
            );  
        }
    });
    //Load default:
    $imageContainer.append(
                "<img id='imageToggleDef"+
                "' src='"+defImage+
                "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"' />"
    );
    //Toggle images:
    function loadImage(imageId) {
        $imageContainer.stop(true).fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $(this).find('img').hide();
            $(this).find('img#'+imageId).show();
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

This is Code 1. I am trying to combine this with Code 2 while still using get_terms instead of wp_list_categories. Ive noticed that you cant explode the results from get_terms, but having trouble where $i seems to be a string and not a number....Its over my head and Im getting lots of errors.

```
// First, define these.
$max_cat_count = 32; // this is 'x'
$qty_per_column = 8; // this is 'y'

// Then the $args array.
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'number'     => $max_cat_count + 1, // keep the + 1
    'title_li'   => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'echo'       => 0,
    'style'      => '',
    // ... your other args here ...
);

// Get the categories list.
$get_cats = wp_list_categories( $args );

// Split the list into array items.
$cat_array = explode( "<br />", $get_cats );

$total = count( $cat_array );
$list_number = 1;
$_new_col = false;

foreach ( $cat_array as $i => $category ) {
    if ( $i >= $max_cat_count ) {
        break;
    }

    if ( $i % $qty_per_column === 0 ) {
        // Close previous column, if any.
        if ( $_new_col ) {
            echo '</div><!-- .cat_columns -->' . "\n";
        }

        // Open new column.
        $id = 'cat-col-' . $list_number;
        echo '<div class="cat_columns" id="' . $id . '">' . "\n";

        $_new_col = true;
        $list_number++; // increment the columns count
    }

    if ( $total > $max_cat_count && $i === $max_cat_count - 1 ) {
        // Make sure to change the # to the proper URL.
        echo "\t" . '<div><a href="#">View All</a></div>' . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "\t" . '<div>' . trim( $category ) . '</div>' . "\n";
    }
}
// Close last column, if any.
if ( $_new_col ) {
    echo '</div><!-- .cat_columns -->' . "\n";
}
```

This is what the output looks like:
[image]

Comment: So referring to the "Code 1", *where* should the thumbnail appear? After the `div` with the category link/name?

Comment: before the very first column of categories is listed, to the left.

Comment: You mean, a list of thumbnails to the left of the first `.cat_columns` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9zr74emq/)?.. If yes, you can just use CSS?

Comment: There is actually some more to the code which uses the data tag to display the relevant thumbnail on hover of the category. I left it out because I thought it might confuse things, but have now added it above to Code 2.

Comment: So you want to replace that `<div>Category Name</div>` (in Code 1) with that `<li>Category Name</li>` (in Code 2) ? If not, can you show an image with the current display (or HTML output) and the expected one?

Comment: Have just updated above to show an image of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modified PHP code

```php
<?php
// First, define these.
$max_cat_count = 32; // this is 'x'
$qty_per_column = 8; // this is 'y'

// Then the $args array.
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'number'     => $max_cat_count + 1, // keep the + 1
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    // ... your other args here ...
);

// Get the categories list.
$get_cats = get_terms( $args );
$get_cats = ( ! is_wp_error( $get_cats ) ) ? $get_cats : [];

// Default thumbnail URL.
$default_thumb = content_url( '/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder-100x100.png' );

$total = count( $get_cats );
$list_number = 1;
$_new_col = false;

$columns = '';
foreach ( $get_cats as $i => $cat ) {
    if ( $i >= $max_cat_count ) {
        break;
    }

    if ( $i % $qty_per_column === 0 ) {
        // Close previous column, if any.
        if ( $_new_col ) {
            $columns .= '</ul></div><!-- .cat_columns -->';
        }

        // Open new column.
        $id = 'cat-col-' . $list_number;
        $columns .= '<div class="menu cat_columns" id="' . $id . '">';
        $columns .= '<ul class="hoverimage">';

        $_new_col = true;
        $list_number++; // increment the columns count
    }

    if ( $total > $max_cat_count && $i === $max_cat_count - 1 ) {
        // Make sure to change the # to the proper URL.
        $columns .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">View All</a></li>';
    } else {
        $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = $thumbnail_id ? wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ) : '';
        // If $image is empty, just let it be. JS will set it to $default_thumb.
        // That way, the page source/HTML will be less.

        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $cat ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $cat->name ) . '</a>';
        $columns .= '<li class="menu-item" data-image="' . esc_url( $image ) . '">' . $link . '</li>';
    }
}
// Close last column, if any.
if ( $_new_col ) {
    $columns .= '</ul></div><!-- .cat_columns -->';
}
?>
<div class="design">
    <div class="zoom-preview">
        <div class="img_container" data-default_thumb="<?php echo esc_url( $default_thumb ); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $columns; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

### Modified jQuery code

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){
    var imageContainer = '.img_container',
        imageList      = '.hoverimage',
        maxWidth       = '100%'; // parent or specific css width;

    var $imageContainer = $(imageContainer).eq(0);
    var $imageList      = $(imageList);

    /*
     * I moved this var to here, and use data-default_thumb to specify the
     * default thumbnail URL. That way, you can - and should - avoid using
     * PHP in JS. So your opening DIV tag would look like:
     * <div class="img_container" data-default_thumb="http://example.com/image.png">
     */
    var defImage        = $imageContainer.data( 'default_thumb' );

    if (maxWidth === 'parent') {
        maxWidth = $imageContainer.width() + 'px';
    }

    // Load images and set hover::
    $imageList.find('li[data-image]').each(function(index){
        if (typeof $(this).data('image') === 'string') {
            var thumb_url = $( this ).data( 'image' ) || defImage;
            $imageContainer.append(
                "<img id='imageToggle"+index+
                "' src='"+ thumb_url +
                "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"; max-height:100%; display:none;' />"
            );
            $(this).data("image","imageToggle"+index);
            $(this).hover(
                function(){ loadImage($(this).data('image')); },
                function(){ loadImage('imageToggleDef'); }
            );
        }
    });

    // Load default:
    $imageContainer.append(
        "<img id='imageToggleDef"+
        "' src='"+defImage+
        "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"; max-height:100%' />"
    );

    // Toggle images:
    function loadImage(imageId) {
        $imageContainer.stop(true).fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $(this).find('img').hide();
            $(this).find('img#'+imageId).show();
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
});
```

### Sample CSS code

```css
.cat_columns {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.zoom-preview {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

So basically, just "play" with the CSS to get the proper layout — e.g. without the thumbnail preview, the `.cat_columns` would have a width of `25%` (to have a total of 4 columns in a row).

And after you implemented all the code, the generated markup/HTML would look something like so:

```html
<div class="design">
  <div class="zoom-preview">
    <div class="img_container" data-default_thumb="{Default thumbnail URL}">
      {Thumbnails added via JS}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu cat_columns">
    <ul class="hoverimage">
      <li class="menu-item" data-image="{Thumbnail URL}"><a href="{Category URL}">{Category Name}</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" data-image="{Thumbnail URL}"><a href="{Category URL}">{Category Name}</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu cat_columns">
    <ul class="hoverimage">
      <li class="menu-item" data-image="{Thumbnail URL}"><a href="{Category URL}">{Category Name}</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item" data-image="{Thumbnail URL}"><a href="{Category URL}">{Category Name}</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

[Try a demo on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t7a4sgd/)

### Additional Notes

1. The arguments `title_li`, `echo`, `style` and `show_count` are to be used with `wp_list_categories()`, and have no effects in `get_terms()`.
2. I used [`content_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/content_url/) to retrieve the WordPress "content" URL which looks like `http://example.com/wp-content`.
3. After you've tested everything, you should put the jQuery script in an external script and use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and `wp_enqueue_script()` to load the script. (I've recently posted [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/352232) which might help you with `wp_enqueue_script()`.)

### UPDATE

If you want the default thumbnail to be loaded immediately, then you should manually add the `<img>` to the HTML:

```php
<!-- With this version, no need for data-default_thumb -->
<div class="img_container">
        <img id="imageToggleDef" src="<?php echo esc_url( $default_thumb ); ?>" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" />
</div>
```

You can try a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0t7a4sgd/1/) and be sure to use the JS there and not the one originally posted above.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much for taking the time to write such a comprehensive answer! This has also solved another issue I was having with the thumbnails showing up intermittently and requiring multiple page refreshes. I will follow your instructions for the external script as I think that may also solve the slight delay in the default thumbnail showing up.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I forgot that (in the JS) the `$imageList.find('li')` should be `$imageList.find('li[data-image]')` :)

Comment: Ok have changed that. I have used wp_enqueue_scripts hook and wp_enqueue_script() to load the script in my functions.php. Is there any need to include a script src url in the php file where the rest of the code is? The php is included into a drop down menu. Also as the default thumbnail is delayed, the category columns float left and then shift back once it loads. Is there something I have done wrong with the enqueuing? Is it necessary to load jquery library in wordpress?

Comment: Check the updated answer (basically just that "UPDATE" part) and if you still have questions, let me know. Edit: That second fiddle/demo still has `data-default_thumb`, but it's not needed - I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: ok so it is loading faster than before but the categories still beat the thumbnail into the left column until the page is finished loading

Comment: Hi Whee. If the issue is still there, I suggest you to create a fiddle demonstrating the issue and then ask a question on SO. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks again Sally. Ive looked into it and its called "image reflow" incase anyone else has the same issue.